# make is rebuilding entire project when only one .c file has changed

Tags: c, makefile, mingw

I wrote the following makefile:

```
CC = cxs12x
CFLAGS = +hcs -l +rev +fast +debug +sprec -pnp -gi -gsf -gdv -s -oc
SOURCES = MAIN.C vector.c can.c allegro3930.c regulatorctrl.c timer.c adc.c
SOURCESS2 = $(SOURCES:.c=.s)
SOURCESS = $(SOURCESS2:.C=.s)
OBJECTS2 = $(SOURCES:.c=.o)
OBJECTS = $(OBJECTS2:.C=.o)

AS = cas12x
AFLAGS = -l
ASOURCES = CRT0.asm
ASOURCESS = $(ASOURCES:.asm=.s)
AOBJECT = $(ASOURCES:.asm=.o)

OBJLIST = objlist.lkf
ORDEREDOBJLIST = bklist

LDFLAGS = 
LD = clnk
LINKERSCRIPT = lds12.lkf

TARGET = foo

$(TARGET).bin : $(TARGET)raw.bin
    cmd /c del $(TARGET).bin
    c:\utils\encraesf $(TARGET)raw.bin $(TARGET).bin

$(TARGET)raw.bin : $(TARGET).mot
    del $(TARGET)raw.bin
    c:\utils\srec2bin $(TARGET)raw.bin -K 256 -dFF -v 0 -s $(TARGET).mot
    c:\utils\stamp $(TARGET)raw.bin 3dee0

$(TARGET).mot : $(TARGET).out
    cmd /c del $(TARGET).mot
    chex -s -f3 -o$(TARGET).s19 $(TARGET).out   #for cyclone
    chex -s -b0x7c0000 -f3 -o$(TARGET).mot $(TARGET).out

$(TARGET).out : $(OBJECTS) $(AOBJECT)
    cmd /c del $@
    $(LD) -o$@ -m$(TARGET).map $(LINKERSCRIPT)
    cvdwarf -v -loc $@
    cv695 -v $@
    clabs $@

$(AOBJECT) : $(ASOURCESS)
    $(AS) $(AFLAGS) $(ASOURCESS)

$(OBJECTS) : $(SOURCESS)
    $(AS) $(AFLAGS) $(SOURCESS)

$(ASOURCESS) : $(ASOURCES)
    copy $*.asm $*.s

$(SOURCESS) : $(SOURCES)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(SOURCES)

clean:
    cmd /c DEL /F /Q $(OBJECTS) $(AOBJECT) $(SOURCESS) $(ASOURCESS) $(ORDEREDOBJLIST) $(OBJECTS:.o=.ls) $(OBJECTS:.o=.la) $(AOBJECT:.o=.ls) $(AOBJECT:.o=.la) $(TARGET).bin $(TARGET)raw.bin $(TARGET).mot $(TARGET).out $(TARGET).s19 $(TARGET).map
```

I'm sure there are many problems with the way I'm doing things in this makefile (mostly centered around the fact that I'm mostly using 'lists of files' in all the commands, rather than the built-in automatic vartiables (`$^`, etc). It builds a target as-is, but the main problem I'm having is that it recompiles all the prerequisites rather than just the ones that have changes since the last build. I'd like a hand in converting this over to using automatic variables for the prerequisites, rather than the 'list of files in a variable' approach that i'm currently using (ie `$(SOURCES)`). I'd be happy to hear of any other problems you see with the above makefile, too!

I'm using MINGW make, but I'd like the makefile to be portable between GNU, NMAKE, etc.

*edit*: The output is shown below (a single file was changed - adc.c, and you can see that everything is rebuilt...)

```
C:\projects\svn\ecap\Firmware\Application>c:/mingw/bin/mingw32-make
cxs12x +hcs -l +rev +fast +debug +sprec -pnp -gi -gsf -gdv -s -oc MAIN.C vector.
c can.c allegro3930.c regulatorctrl.c timer.c adc.c
MAIN.C:
vector.c:
can.c:
allegro3930.c:
regulatorctrl.c:
timer.c:
adc.c:
cas12x -l MAIN.s vector.s can.s allegro3930.s regulatorctrl.s timer.s adc.s
cmd /c del foo.out
clnk -ofoo.out -mfoo.map lds12.lkf
cvdwarf -v -loc foo.out
Reading Debug Symbols ..
     For file: 9s12p128.h
     For file: adc.c
     For file: allegro3930.c
     For file: timer.c
     For file: regulatorctrl.c
     For file: can.c
     For file: MAIN.C
     For file: vector.c
Outputing HEADER PART
Outputing PROGRAM HEADER PART
Outputing IMAGE LOAD PART
Outputing SYMBOLS TABLE PART
Outputing IMAGE DEBUG PART
Outputing LINES INFO
     For file: vector.c
     For file: MAIN.C
     For file: can.c
     For file: regulatorctrl.c
     For file: timer.c
     For file: allegro3930.c
     For file: adc.c
Outputing DEBUG INFO
     For file: 9s12p128.h
Getting SPACE CODING
        for globals ...
        for functions ...
     For file: adc.c
Getting SPACE CODING
        for globals ...
        for functions ...
     For file: allegro3930.c
Getting SPACE CODING
        for globals ...
        for functions ...
     For file: timer.c
Getting SPACE CODING
        for globals ...
        for functions ...
     For file: regulatorctrl.c
Getting SPACE CODING
        for globals ...
        for functions ...
     For file: can.c
Getting SPACE CODING
        for globals ...
        for functions ...
     For file: MAIN.C
Getting SPACE CODING
        for globals ...
        for functions ...
     For file: vector.c
Getting SPACE CODING
        for globals ...
        for functions ...
Outputing DEBUG ABBREV
Outputing DEBUG LOCATION
Outputing DEBUG FRAME
Outputing STRING TABLE PART
Outputing SECTION NAME TABLE PART
Outputing SECTIONS TABLE PART
cv695 -v foo.out
Loading Line Information
          For file:        adc.c (file n° 1)
          For file:        allegro3930.c (file n° 2)
          For file:        timer.c (file n° 3)
          For file:        regulatorctrl.c (file n° 4)
          For file:        can.c (file n° 5)
          For file:        MAIN.C (file n° 6)
          For file:        vector.c (file n° 7)
Outputing HEADER PART
Outputing EXTENSION PART
Outputing ENVIRONMENT PART
Outputing SECTION PART
Outputing PUBLIC/EXTERNAL PART
Outputing IMAGE DEBUG PART
SOURCE FILE:9s12p128.h
        Registering types ...  for globals ...  for functions ...
                Outputing Globals
                Outputing line info
SOURCE FILE:adc.c
        Registering types ...  for globals ...  for functions ...
                Outputing Globals
                Outputing info for function tim4svc()
                Outputing info for function adcInit()
                Outputing line info
SOURCE FILE:allegro3930.c
        Registering types ...  for globals ...  for functions ...
                Outputing Globals
                Outputing info for function tim1svc()
                Outputing info for function tim3svc()
                Outputing info for function allegro3930UpdateDuty()
                Outputing info for function allegro3930Init()
                Outputing line info
SOURCE FILE:timer.c
        Registering types ...  for globals ...  for functions ...
                Outputing Globals
                Outputing info for function tosvc()
                Outputing info for function timerInit()
                Outputing line info
SOURCE FILE:regulatorctrl.c
        Registering types ...  for globals ...  for functions ...
                Outputing Globals
                Outputing info for function tim2svc()
                Outputing info for function regulatorCtrlStartZeroSpan()
                Outputing info for function regulatorCtrlDoZeroSpan()
                Outputing info for function regulatorCtrlDoPositionCtrl()
                Outputing info for function regulatorCtrlInit()
                Outputing info for function binSearch()
                Outputing info for function getFrac()
                Outputing info for function interp1d()
                Outputing line info
SOURCE FILE:can.c
        Registering types ...  for globals ...  for functions ...
                Outputing Globals
                Outputing info for function can0rxsvc()
                Outputing info for function tim0svc()
                Outputing info for function canInit()
                Outputing info for function txextmsg()
                Outputing line info
SOURCE FILE:MAIN.C
        Registering types ...  for globals ...  for functions ...
                Outputing Globals
                Outputing info for function main()
                Outputing info for function stopallints()
                Outputing info for function dummyf()
                Outputing line info
SOURCE FILE:vector.c
        Registering types ...  for globals ...  for functions ...
                Outputing Globals
                Outputing info for function unusedv()
                Outputing line info
Outputing IMAGE LOAD PART
clabs foo.out
cmd /c del foo.mot
chex -s -f3 -ofoo.s19 foo.out   #for cyclone
chex -s -b0x7c0000 -f3 -ofoo.mot foo.out
del fooraw.bin
c:\utils\srec2bin fooraw.bin -K 256 -dFF -v 0 -s foo.mot
c:\utils\stamp fooraw.bin 3dee0
Writing date stamp at 0003dee0
Date Stamp:  2014.07.05 17:17:56
cmd /c del foo.bin
c:\utils\encraesf fooraw.bin foo.bin
```

Comment: What does your make output look like?

Comment: It is aconventional to 'manually' invoke the assembler on the C compiler output.  Normally, you let the C compiler do that, simply creating the object file from the `.c` source file.  I'd not be surprised to find that the handling of assembler is causing your problems, but I've not worked out how or why.  (The C compiler removes assembler files automatically, assuming it even generates them explicitly in the first place.)

Comment: I have to admit, I don't really pay much attention to the intermediate  .s files, but many of my coworkers do. We've actually found several compiler bugs this way. As a result, we (as an organization) kind of just generate these by default. When in Rome...

Answer (score 2):

The basic problem is rules like this:

```
$(SOURCESS) : $(SOURCES)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(SOURCES)
```

So *all* members of `SOURCES` are prerequisites of *every* member of `SOURCESS`; change one file, e.g. `vector.c`, and Make considers all of the targets (`MAIN.s vector.s can.s allegro3930.s regulatorctrl.s timer.s adc.s`) out of date and in need of rebuilding.

I suggest a tighter rule, something along the lines of this:

```
%.s : %.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $<
```

Note that  **this might not work as written,** because you are using MINGW Make and you are using ".C" for one source file and ".c" for the rest (I'm sure you have your reasons). Also you're playing with the assembler. So I can't test this solution, I can only point out the problem.

Comment: Thanks, Beta, this is what I guessed. Unfortunately, I ran into a number of problems trying to do things this way. For starters, how to I integrate my 'source file list'? ie. how do i define the .c, .C, and .asm files that compose my projects? I also seem to recall having trouble with the linking step where I'm using 2 sets of prerequisites: both assembly-generated object files, and c-generated object files. As for the .C, and .c business, I really just wanted my makefile to be robust. I often find myself integrating legacy code into my project which often has inconsistent 'c/C' capitalization